# How to export data with duplicate column names using SQL Server Import Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2012

I have one scenario in which I am getting a lot of employee data like address, qualification, work experience, etc from different tables into a new table.

In the required result set there are a few columns which have same(duplicate) name.
For example the `address` column appears multiple times. In my new table I have these column names saved as `Address1`, `Address2`, etc and while using select command I am using alias to rename the result set from `address1` or `address2` to `address`.

I would like to export this data using `SQL server Import Export Wizard`
but the problem is that SQL won't let me export the result set with duplicate column names(since I have fetched the results using same alias for multiple columns).

The Error I get is

> Could not connect source component. Error 0xc0207015

Comment: You lost me there at the end. You have a select statement, you understand how to provide an alias for the columns - why is that not working with the Import/Export wizard?

Comment: I am able to get the results with select statement.
While exporting the result set, my statements gets successfully parsed too.
I am able to view the preview too.
Just dont know whats stopping it from getting exported.
And thank you for the revert.

Comment: Don't apologize for first posts. It's redundant. It's not part of the issue and comments will help direct to missing information or any SO FAQs to read if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong, but you can alias columns just fine in the import/export wizard.

In my source selection, I was given the choice between tables and Query, I selected Query and used the following query.

```
SELECT
    P.Address AS Address1
,   P.Person
,   A.Address AS Address2
,   A.City
FROM (SELECT 1 AS Address, 2 AS Person) P 
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT 1 AS Address, 3 AS City) AS A
```

[image]

I chose to export to flat file and my resulting file looked like

```
Address1,Person,Address2,City
1,2,1,3
```

Comment: I need same alias for multiple columns:
e.g. 
SELECT
    Address1 AS Address
,   Person
,   Address2 AS Address
,   City
FROM  A